# Use 'cv::pointPolygonTest'

Tags: opencv

I'm writing some code to test if a point is inside the contour of a polygon.
I have started writing my own code but i see this function is defined. The problem is I don't understand why the contour is a `Mat`. I have the contour of the polygon into a vector of `CvPoint`.

Function declaration:
`double pointPolygonTest(const Mat& contour, Point2f pt, bool measureDist)`

Anyone have an example of how to work with this function or know how to convert a vector of `CvPoint` to a `const Mat& contour`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#pointpolygontest) shows the first argument as an array: `double pointPolygonTest(InputArray contour, Point2f pt, bool measureDist)`. The sample code in [`samples/cpp/tutorial_code/ShapeDescriptors/pointPolygonTest_demo.cpp`](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/samples/cpp/tutorial_code/ShapeDescriptors/pointPolygonTest_demo.cpp) passes a vector of Point vectors.

Perhaps you're looking at outdated documentation?